# "fresh and relaxed"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

I have to identify the syntax used in these two sentences and explain.

A. *After a short vacation in Japan, Mr Chang appeared in my office, fresh and relaxed.*

B. *After a short vacation in Japan, Mr Chang appeared fresh and relaxed in my office.*

So far, I was trying to break down the phrases used in the sentences like this:

- In both sentences it can be analysed that it starts off with a prepositional phrase *After a short vacation in Japan*.
- My understanding is prepositional phrase is a group of words made up of a preposition, its object, and any of the object's modifiers.
- Then it moves along to the subject of the sentence, Mr Chang.
- The word *appeared* in the sentences is a verb.

Is that correct? Could you please help?

Comment: The culture and rules of the site ask people who ask questions to show their own thoughts, attempts at an answer, and research, in the question, before asking others (us) to help.

Comment: well so far I was trying to breakdown the phrases used in the sentences. In both sentences it can be analysed that it starts off with a prepositional phrase ‘After a short vacation in Japan’. A prepositional phrase is a group of words made up of a preposition, its object, and any of the object's modifiers. If that is correct? Then it moves along to the subject of the sentence, Mr Chang. the word Appeared in the sentences are verbs

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Thanks! I've [edit]ed your question so all this useful information is available in the body of it, in one place.  It's better than than in comments, which are messy and sometimes disappear.  It's best to include all such details in the write-up when you post a question (useful info for next time)

Comment: Please ask yourself whether Mr. Chang was really fresh and relaxed, or did he merely appear to be?

Comment: Thanks Dan Bron! I am Sorry as it's my first times using this site so I wasn't aware of the rules :) Just trying to gather some insight on the grammar used in these sentence so I can understand it more clearly.

Comment: Would this be more suited to https://ell.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Ddddan Definitely not, old bean.

Comment: @Araucaria So answer! You know we’re short on actually syntacticians around here.

Comment: So far so good, but "fresh and relaxed" has a different function in B than in A, because of the lack of commas.